# Retrieving HTML code from SQL database in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, sql-server, label

I have some code stored in SQL database that is in from of HTML code
For example in the database I have stored

```
<b>Lorem Ipsum</b>
```

When I retrieve that data from sql and input it into a label it shows something like

```
&lt;b&gtLorem Ipsum&lt;/b&gt;
```

but I want it to use html code so that formatting is available.

Comment: Then you have stored your html code as html_entities. This means that, when you output it on a webpage, the html code will be displayed and not rendered. I think your error is in the routine that stores the html in the db. Please show us that code, so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The `Label` control encodes whatever value you set it to. Don't use a `Label`, use a `Literal` instead.

`<asp:Literal ID="litExample"></asp:Literal>`

Then set it's `Text` property:

`litExample.Text = "<b>Lorem Ipsum</b>";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span too:

```
<span runat="server" id="mySpan" />
```

Then set InnerHtml property:

```
mySpan.InnerHtml = [...];
```

Sometimes it's better to use System.Web.UI.HtmlControls instead of System.Web.UI.WebControls because they create a cleaner and smaller HTML output.